# How to write oracle SQL query to get matching and non-matching pair of rows (on the basis of key columns) in a certain order

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have a below sample data:

```
ID  BOOK_NAME  AUTHOR  YEAR  PAGE_COUNT  PRICE  BUCKET
1   Book1      A1      2001  450         44     1
2   Book2      A2      2002  550         50     1
3   Book1      A1      2001  450         44     2
4   Book3      A3      2003  350         38     1
5   Book2      A2      2002  550         50     2
6   Book3      A3      2003  350         38     2
7   Book4      A4      2006  400         60     1
8   Book4      A4      2006  410         60     2
9   Book5      A5      1999  600         58     1
10  Book6      A6      2004  650         76     2
```

The above sample data has books from two buckets - 1 & 2. The requirement is to order the books in a way to show matching and non-matching books between both the buckets i.e. a book is called **MATCHED** if it is present in both the buckets (by matching key columns - **BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR, YEAR, PAGE_COUNT, PRICE**) and **UNMATCHED** if otherwise. Even if a single column doesn't match between both the buckets for any pair, the book is considered **UNMATCHED**. Below is the expected output from the above input.

```
STATUS     ID  BOOK_NAME  AUTHOR  YEAR  PAGE_COUNT  PRICE  BUCKET
MATCHED    2   Book2      A2      2002  550         50     1
MATCHED    5   Book2      A2      2002  550         50     2
MATCHED    1   Book1      A1      2001  450         44     1
MATCHED    3   Book1      A1      2001  450         44     2
MATCHED    4   Book3      A3      2003  350         38     1
MATCHED    6   Book3      A3      2003  350         38     2
UNMATCHED  7   Book4      A4      2006  400         60     1
UNMATCHED  9   Book5      A5      1999  600         58     1
UNMATCHED  10  Book6      A6      2004  650         76     2
UNMATCHED  8   Book4      A4      2006  410         60     2
```

Additionally-

1. The matched pairs should be ordered by **PRICE** column i.e. pair with highest price should come first.
2. In the unmatched section of the list, the items should be ordered by bucket i.e. all the bucket 1 unmatched items should come together and then all the bucket 2 unmatched items should come.
3. For each bucket in the unmatched section, the items then further should be ordered by **PRICE** column i.e. pair with highest price should come first.

So, the problem is all about ordering the data set in section wise rules. Please help with a single query solution, I know it can be done easily by fetching the data and applying the logic in any coding language like Java. But based on design requirements, I am interested in a simple SQL based solution. Please help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Assuming the books don't have duplicates *within* a bucket:

```
select (case when count(*) over (partition by BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR, YEAR, PAGE_COUNT, PRICE) = 2
             then 'Matched' else 'Unmatched'
        end) as status,
       t.*
from t
order by status,
         (case when count(*) over (partition by BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR, YEAR, PAGE_COUNT, PRICE) = 2 then price end) desc,
         bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Gordon! It gave me the direction for solving my problem. I made few adjustments below to suit my need.

```
select (case when count(*) over (partition by BOOK_NAME, AUTHOR, YEAR, PAGE_COUNT, PRICE) = 2
             then 'Matched' else 'Unmatched'
        end) as status,
       t.*
from t
order by status,
         (case when status = 'Matched' then price end) desc,
         (case when status = 'Unmatched' then bucket end),
         (case when status = 'Matched' then BOOK_NAME end),
         (case when status = 'Matched' then AUTHOR end),
         (case when status = 'Matched' then YEAR end),
         (case when status = 'Matched' then PAGE_COUNT end),
         (case when status = 'Matched' then bucket end),
         (case when status = 'Unmatched' then price end) desc
```